# How do i install Adobe AIR SDK 2.6 on OSX?

Tags: ios, sdk, air, adobe, flash-cs5

I have the AIR sdk 2.5 installed (CS5 Flash Professional), but I can't figure out how to update it to 2.6.  I downloaded the package, but where do I put it?  No place seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this myself. I think the 2.5 sdk was part of a Flash CS5 update. Thinking one might have to use 2.6 via command-line ADT, which I find a pain in the butt. But the new iOS features are incentive!!!

Comment: Figured out the command line tool at least.  Publish an air intermediate file and type this in terminal:

/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CS5/AIR2.6/bin/adt -package -target ipa-test -provisioning-profile provProf.mobileprovision -storetype pkcs12 -keystore Certificates.p12 iPadGame.ipa iPadGame.airi

replace provProf, certificates, and iPadGame names with your file paths.

replace ipa-test with ipa-debug, ipa-app-store, ipa-ad-hoc as needed.